# Obtain a List of orders from a List of products for the given product category

Tags: java, java-stream

OrderList - Id, Status, Product List.

ProductList - Id, Name, category.

Obtain a list of order with List of products belong to category “Baby” Java 8

I have tried

```
orderList.stream().flatMap(prodCat -> prodCat.getProduct().stream())
        .filter(cat -> cat.getCategary()=="Baby").forEach(System.out::println);
```

It return list of product type only. I am looking for return list of order of list product.

Comment: There is relation one to many between order and Product, So return List of order with filtered product list according category.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for orders that have some product with a certain category, you can use `anyMatch()` in a `filter()`, like this:

```
orderList.stream()
        .filter(o -> o.getProducts()
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(p -> p.getCategory().equals("Baby")))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: but it return all data from product list of anyMatch category.

Answer (score 0):

If want to obtain the result of execution of the stream pipeline as a `List` you should use [`collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)) as terminal operation and [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()) as its argument.

Or as an alternative available with **Java 16** onwards you might use [`toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) as a terminal operation, which returns an *immutable list*.

The method below iterates over the list of **orders** and creates a *new* instance of `Order` for every object that contains in its list of **products** *at least one* **product** of a given **category** otherwise, the **order** will be *discarded*. Then orders get collected to a new list.

```
public static List<Order> getOrdersOfCategory(List<Order> orderList, String category) {
    return orderList.stream()
            .map(order -> getNewOrderOfCategory(order, category)) // creating a new Order object that contains a filtered List of products
            .filter(Optional::isPresent) // removing the orders that have no products of a given category at all
            .map(Optional::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The responsibility of the method below is to create new instances of `Order` class. Each of them will be associated with a *filtered list of products*.

Result returned by this method is of type `Optional<Order>` in order to represent a situation when a filtered list of products is *empty* and order is *discarded*.

```
public static Optional<Order> getNewOrderOfCategory(Order order, String category) {
    List<Product> filteredProducts = getProductsOfCategory(order.getProduct(), category);

    return filteredProducts.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : // no target products
                                        new Order(order.getId(),
                                                  order.getStatus(),
                                                  filteredProducts);
}
```

This method is used to extract the products of a given **category** from the given list.

```
public static List<Product> getProductsOfCategory(List<Product> products, String category) {
    return products.stream()
            .filter(prod -> prod.getCategary().equals(category))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**Note**

- Don't compare objects with a double equals sign, always use method `equals()` instead;
- It'll be better to implement product category as an **enum** instead of relying on a string. All product categories will be defined in one place and if you'll make a typo it'll be pretty obvious because the code will not compile.

Comment: I am looking Order list with filtered product list. Order have list of product, Return type is List<Order> instead of List<Product>. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right except for `equals` between strings.
Pay attention:

This equality is **false** because it compares the references:

```java
"Baby" == new String("Baby")
```

This equality is **true** because it compares the values:

```java
"Baby".equals(new String("Baby"))
```

This is the final result:

```java
orderList.stream()
         .flatMap(prodCat -> prodCat.getProduct().stream())
         .filter(cat -> "Baby".equals(cat.getCategary()))
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Actually `"Baby" == "Baby"` is true.

Comment: I changed the equality.